# Bloqueio de fmdados VBa

Tags: excel-vba

Criei um formulario simples que me informa data, data, OS e Tipo. Quando meu usuario tentan alterar algum ele nao consegue pois progamei para q ficasse boqueado a alteraçao dos dados mas quando meu cliente seleciona todas as celulas da planilha e aperta dele apaga tudo!
Gostaria de saber como bloquear e ele nao apagar as celexcs, nao quero salvar a planilha apenas bloquear a açao de excluscadastraments pois ele ficara usando o dia todo o cadastramento?

Comment: É bom fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender a fazer uma pergunta.

Comment: Fmdados? Celexcs?

Comment: É só proteger a planilha clicando na guia Revisão